# mysql and php - dont know how to select and echo

Tags: php, mysql, web, xampp

My question is.... i have a table with 2 columns and 24 rows.

first column is only id and it goes from 1 to 24 and second column is some text in each row and follows id.

i don't know how to SELECT text from each row separated by id in first column and echo it.

I am using xampp - mysql and working in php. TY

i tried something like this and than i used variable $row to call row 0. but i think thats not right way.

```
$nap_query = "SELECT napomena FROM napomena";

$nap_result = mysql_query($nap_query) or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($nap_result);
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky that would not work with mysql_fetch_row.
With respect to the question, find some tutorial to learn the basics.

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/mysql_query. Always. First thing you do. Read it.

Comment: but i want to echo one row from table in one switch case, i have 24 switch cases and i need 24 echos

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the php mysql_fetch_array documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

As the comments suggest `mysql_fetch_row` doesn't work for multiple rows. 
So you can do that

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($nap_result)) 
    echo $row['napomena'];
```

**Aditions** 
It's best not to use `mysql` anymore and use `mysqli` or prefebly `PDO` in order to handle database connections. Read [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) documentation here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only one row result

```
$rownum=0; //zero or something
echo mysql_result($nap_result, $rownum, "napomena");
```

Multi values use mysql_fetch_array

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($nap_result)){
  echo $row['napomena'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nap_query = "SELECT field FROM table";

$nap_result = mysql_query($nap_query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($nap_result))
 echo $row['field'].'<br/>';
```

This will result like this
resultA
resultB
resultC
etc

Just like @punitha said, it's better to use PDO